# A question about Marriage

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, ramayana, marriage, itihasa

It is said in Manusmriti that a Brahmana may marry a Brahmana girl of his own race(same country probably) then girls of lower varnas..
In itihasas and puranas we find examples of Sages marrying daughters of kings but they were all located near ashram of the sage(i.e in  same kingdom)..
Is there any example of a Brahmana Sage marrying a Ksatriya or a Brahmana girl from a distant country(Rajya)?
Kindly answer(with scriptural proof if possible)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please dont generalise marriage. Manu Smriti clearly defines Manu DHARMA for mutualism between MALE&FEMALE. The following though may seem funny in modern era, is even applicable nowadays;

Confusion must not arise in differentiating Brahmana - Sage - Rakshaka -  Lakshana - Raagnya

All above sects are different.

Brahmana : does not marry but female(girl of own race/ compatible race) is married to Him(Thyself) to attain liberation.

Sage: There are no restrictions for sages and a sage can have one wife but can help many women to be followers of his teachings. Those abandoned women are reenergised by sage through good practices.

Rakshaka: A man marrying two blood-born sisters to protect them against desirous illwitted society is valid.

Lakshana: The most attractive among men is already a Virtual hero of impact for many girls who think about hero though they get married to their husbands. Its impact may be in genes.

Raagya: A emperor does not marry girls physically after conquest but annexes the wives of kings who lost their lives in wars. Though victim wives(queens) may not like the conquerer the Emperor though conquered has to feed all queens till their death, because

Man did not fight in war against a king's woman to persuade victory over both males & females. A victory in war is over human males only due to non-participation of women in wars.